# Joomla 3.3 Fabrik 3.1 email plugin

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to send an email after adding a record using Fabrik form. I do get the email but no matter what I change, I always get the same email format including the subject. Using `debug.php` or `debug_with_labels.php` templates don't make any difference. I gave full control to everyone to `plugins\fabrik_form\email` folder.

I'm on Windows 2012 server running XAMPP 1.8.3 and PHP 5.5.6

Is the email plugin is broken in Joomla 3.3?

Here are the screenshots:

[image: To tab]

[image: Options tab]

Answer (score 0):

Which form should your eMail have? When I used the plugin, I just created a new template in ../plugins/fabrik_form/email/tmpl that had the text I wanted to be in the eMail.

If you just don't want a subject, why not try to leave that input-field empty?

Comment: This should be in comment section rather than answering.

Comment: Sorry, still new... Should I delete and repost it?

Comment: Well as I need a reputation of 50 to comment on the original post, I think I just leave it the way it is....

Comment: Ohh  no problem then.